# Composite key representation in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, dictionary

I have a C# dictionary with a composite key:

```
IDictionary<Tuple<int, int?>, MyObject> MyObjects
```

What is the best way to represent this data structure in Javascript?

I'd like to be able to access my objects like:

```
var obj = MyObjects[[3,2]];
```

or

```
var obj = MyObjects[[3,null]];
```

Comment: Can you post code to show what `MyObjects` looks like?

Comment: You just don't. JavaScript and C# are completely different languages. Trying to translate a construct from the one to the other is like translating this comment to French, literally. _"Tu justement ne pas"_  is just silly

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, so if that's true would you be able to propose a different data model?

Comment: @steaks: Perhaps a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be something like

```
var myObjects = []; 
myObjects.push({key1:1, key2: 9, value: 22});
myObjects.push({key1:-1, key2: 0, value: 2});
...
```

and after query it with ordinary

```
var foundValues = function(key1, key2) {

   var filteredArray = array.filter(function (element) { 
      return element.key1=== key1 && element.key2 === key2;
   });

   return filteredArray;
}
```

In other words: flatten into one array and project result from the query.

**EDIT**

If you need more performant approach, but slightly more "messy", you can define keys like 
concat strings of the keys you will search for. Referring to prev example:

```
var myObjects = {}; 
myObjects["1_9"] = 22; 
myObjects["-1_0"] = 2;
```

So to access that you write:

```
var foundValues = fucntion(key1, key2) {

   return myObjects[key1.toString() + "_" + key2.toString()];     

}
```

Much more fast, but not so clear when you are reading the code after a while.
For some heavy compute intensive sites I use often this pattern to boost as much as I can performance of picking data I need in right moment.

Comment: I really like this implementation.  In fact, it was my first attempt.  However, I don't think I can do this for performance reasons.  I'm trying to avoid an O(n) lookup time.  I should have specified!

Comment: @steaks: at this point consider another solution. I edited my answer.

Comment: I used the solution suggested in your edit with a slight modification.  My C# JSON serializer uses Tuple's toString() method when serializing tuple dictionary keys.  For example, Tuple.Create(1, 2) serializes to "(1, 2)".  I chose to be consistent , so I access my objects with myObjects["(" + key1.toString() + ", " + key2.toString() + ")"].